# Are the real numbers a lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

A lattice is a set with a partial order, where every pair has a unique upper and lower bound.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the definition that forces the set to be discrete. In particular, the real numbers with their usual partial order and upper/lower bounds seems to fit the definition. But all the examples I've come across are discrete, which makes me wonder if I've missed something. (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples))

Comment: You're not missing anything. Every totally ordered set is a lattice.

Comment: You didn't miss anything, the real numbers form a lattice.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb R$ forms a lattice, but note that $\mathbb R$ is not *lattice-complete*. A partially ordered set $P$ is said to be lattice-complete if every non-empty subset $S\subset P$ has both a supremum and an infimum. For example, consider the subset $S = (0, \infty)$; for which $\sup S$ does not exist in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a lattice, every pair must have a least upper bound (called *join*) and greatest lower bound (called *meet*), that is different from it being unique. There can be many upper bounds or lower bounds. The join or meet of a pair however, is unique.

The reals are in fact a particularly nice kind of lattice:

- They are totally ordered, which means that any two elements $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ can be compared and therefore the join and meet can be computed very easily by using $\max(a, b)$ and $\min(a, b)$ respectively.
- When we take a closed interval (e.g. $[0,1]$), then that interval is complete. This means that every subset $A \subseteq [0,1]$ has a least upper bound, in this case given by its supremum $\sup A$. Similarly for a greatest lower bound and the infimum.